# preg_match(): Unknown modifier ':'

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$matches = preg_match('/[^\\/\:*?"<>\|\r\n]+$/', $this->photo);
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
preg_match(): Unknown modifier ':'
```

I know the problem isn't with my regex, cause I tested it in http://www.phpliveregex.com/ and it worked fine.

Comment: A quick note, you should be passing `$matches` in as the third argument to `preg_match` if you want to capture the matched regex result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your delimiters to something else like `@` for example, so your code becomes this `$matches = preg_match('@[^\\/\:*?"<>\|\r\n]+$@', $this->photo);`.

let me know how it went.